# Generating netbeans project with Lwuit

Tags: java-me, netbeans-7, lwuit

I am trying to generate a netbeans project with Lwuit editor. But gets this error message that some library are missing and that WTK 2.5.2 CLDCC Cannot be found. any idea on how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html
Is the location of the library that you must download.
Additionally you may need the wireless toolkit though I am not sure why.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html

If you are writing for mobile devices I strongly recommend that you check out Codename One which is the open source product developed by the original designers at Sun of lwuit. http://www.codenameone.com/